# How to send files from one android device to another which are connected to same wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have a requirement that I need to send a file from one device to another device through WiFi.Both devices connected to same WiFi. Which protocol I have to use for this requirement.
Both are android devices, Connected to same WiFi router and files size might be more than 1MB.

any sample snippets are helpful.

Comment: How do the two devices find each other? Is there a central server they use? Or do you want to do it with local broadcasts? [This](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/) is probably a good choice of server if you want to use HTTP.

Comment: Both devices connect to same wifi router.

Comment: Right, so given that, how do they find each other? (UDP broadcast? Central server they both connect to? Hardcoded IP addresses? Some other way?)

Comment: UDP broadcasts one device IP Address to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need access to the send or receive process from code, I think this application can solve your need [Spriit](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hellberg.spriid&feature=search_result) (In Beta).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say HTTP would be your best choice. You can use [nanohttp](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/) for the server code.